# how to append number to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

i want to pass multiple roles to servlet

```
 var params = {
       username : username,
       password : password       
 };
 var roles = [];  
 var role = $('#role').val();
 if(role.length > 1){
   for(var i = 0;i < role.length;i++){
      roles[i] =  role[i]
    }
 }
 else{
    params.role1 = role[0] ;
 }
```

How to do this so that result look like

```
 var params = {
       username : username,
       password : password,
       role1 : role1,
       role2 : role2,
       roleN : roleN,

  };
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example with a value for the `#role` element and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) since the keys are dynamic

```
var params = {
    username: username,
    password: password
};
var roles = [];
var role = $('#role').val();
for (var i = 0; i < role.length; i++) {
    params['role' + (i + 1)] = role[i]
}
```

Comment: The condition is uncalled for. If there is just one role in the array, iterating over it will yield the exact same result as `params.role1 = role[0]`.

Comment: @DavidHedlund yes you are right... I though the role can be a non array... didn't check the else part correctly

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the collection of roles and assign properties like so:

```
role.forEach(function(r, i) {
    params['role'+(i+1)] = r;
});
```